# How to write with query syntax this?

Tags: c#

I need to count in number of characters in a string, example "minimum" will print
i:2, m:3, n:1, u:1
sorted by character.
my query is:

```
string str = "minimum"

var query = from ele in str
            group ele by ele
            into chars
            orderby chars.Key
            select chars;

foreach (var x in query)
    Console.WriteLine(x.Key + " - " + x.Count());
```

but this format, how is it written in query syntax?

```
var counts = str.GroupBy(c => c)
             .OrderBy(c => c.Key)
             .ToDictionary(grp => grp.Key, grp => grp.Count());
```

or rather, how do I write the ToDictionary(Key,Count) method.

"query" is an IEnumerable, but "counts" is a dictionary. How do I convert to dictionary in the "select"?
.....select new Dictionary(.....what???

```
select new Dictionary<char, int>(chars.Key, chars.Count());    dont work

select chars.ToDictionary<char, int>(chars.Key, chars.Count());  dont work
```

thank you

any evidence, it didn't work

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can simply write

```cs
string str = "minimum";

// Method syntax
var query = str.GroupBy(c => c)
        .OrderBy(c => c.Key);

foreach (var x in query) {
    Console.WriteLine(x.Key + " - " + x.Count());
}
```

`query` is of type `IOrderedEnumerable<IGrouping<char, char>>` as in your example.

Output:

```
i - 2
m - 3
n - 1
u - 1
```

Note that your version with `from ele in str ...` is  the query syntax and my example has the method syntax.

See: [Query Syntax and Method Syntax in LINQ (C#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/query-syntax-and-method-syntax-in-linq)

Note that the method syntax does not require a `Select` at the end. Your query syntax example and my method syntax example both produce exactly the same compiler output.

---

There is no way to create a dictionary in query syntax, but you can combine query and method syntax by putting the query syntax in parentheses and then adding the method syntax:

```cs
var counts = (
        from ele in str
        group ele by ele
        into chars
        orderby chars.Key
        select chars
    )
    .ToDictionary(grp => grp.Key, grp => grp.Count());
```

Comment: perfect.
Is there query syntax for the "ToDictionary()" method?

I would like my query object, to be of type Dictionary, directly from the from, where, etc. clause.

in short, 
var query = from....    (query is a Dictionary)

Sorry for my english
I hope you understand me

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand the question right. Added the missing piece now.

Comment: Great. Your last example Is perfect:   var counts = (.....).ToDictionary.....